# How to get data from an html table to html form?

Tags: php, html, css

I have an HTML table having some data stored in the database. now i want to update my data for this purpose i added an anchor tag at the end of every line. Now i want that after clicking on a link it will give me the record id which is the first TD of HTML table so that i can use this id to get all data on form fields on another file where i create a form to update data.

i can't understand how to create link how to get selected row id of a table.
i am restricted to use PHP HTML CSS only...

i had tried

```
 echo '<a href="update.php ? id = <?php echo $record["id"]?>"/>edit</a>';

 echo '<a href="update.php ? id = <?php echo $rec -> id?>"/>edit</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in the URL and you can get the URL params within the `update.php` using `$_GET['id']`.

```
echo '<a href="?id=<?php echo $rec->id; ?>"/>edit</a>';

// or if an array
echo '<a href="?id=<?php echo $rec['id']; ?>"/>edit</a>';
```

In `update.php` :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
// do the rest using id
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between url.

**Example-**

```
echo '<a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $record["id"]; ?>"/>edit</a>';
```

And get value in **update.php** use **$_GET** or **$_REQUEST**

**Example-**

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
   echo $_REQUST['id'];
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<a class="btn-white btn btn-xs" href="update.php?id=<?php echo $record['id'];?>"><span class="label label-primary">Edit</label></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass values in URL use either **$_GET** or **$_REQUEST**

**Example:-**

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
//Now apply your query here to get data according to $id
?>
```